# Alternative to Notes app from MAC OSX lion

Tags: notes

Is there an alternative app that is similar to MAC OS X lion Notes app which I use on my Ubuntu? I saw my friend using notes app on his Macbook and I really thought it was useful application in day to day office work.

Just for those who dont know about notes app in MAC OSX Lion here is the [link](http://applenapps.com/mac-osx/mountain-lion-the-mac-takes-notes-from-ios.html)

Comment: What characteristics are you looking for specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Tomboy Note. You will find it in Ubuntu Software Center. If you want to install from terminal, then issue this command

```
sudo apt-get install tomboy
```

there is also basket, xournal, kjots for similar task.